# Is Dreamweaver Browser Compatability Check useless or what?

Tags: browser, dreamweaver, compatibility

I'm making a website in DW CS5 and it is underlining my link to my .css file and says there is Browser Compatibility problems. The thing is that it doesnt show me what the problem is, only that there is a X amount of problems. This is getting annoying since I can't hide it and I can't fix it since it won't point out what is wrong. Also it's just ancient browsers that is getting problems. What should I do to solve this/hide this. I don't like when my code gets underlined and I can't get rid of it in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the docked toolbar, you can just right click the tab and close it and it will be gone.  Alternately, you can undock the entire toolbar and then close it and it's gone.

Comment: No I mean the text that gets underlined. It underlines for example the link to my .css file and says there is combatability errors but it wont show me where in the css file the errors are.